# Use argument shortest in C++ code in FFMPEG

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, arguments

I need to set up the argument "-shortest" but in c++ code. I know that I can set up an argument with value for example:

```
 av_opt_set(codecContext, "crf", "28", 0);
```

But here is the thing, there is a value, but in shortest no value.
So how can I set up shortest in c++ code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/oeuwlw/how_to_set_up_shortest_flag_programmatically_c/

So,
***-shortest*** is a part of ffmpeg binary. Not available when working with the libav* libs.

You can set "fflags", "shortest" and "max_interleave_delta", "100M" on the AVFormatContext.